# I am having trouble consolidating Haml

Tags: haml

Is there anyway to put this on one line?  I have read the documentation and still having trouble.

```
%script
  var Foo =
  = bar.baz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [interpolation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_):

```
%script
  var Foo = #{bar.baz}
```

or even (if the entire script will fit on one line):

```
%script var Foo = #{bar.baz}
```